# A "gradient" weak Harnack inequality for quasilinear elliptic equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, elliptic-pde

Suppose we are in the following loosely described setting:
we have a non-negative supersolution $h$ of the following elliptic equation:
\begin{equation}
\Delta h + \|\nabla h\|^2 + f(x) \geq 0
\end{equation}
Having all the needed regularity, is it possible to control
\begin{equation}
R^{1-n} \int_{B_{R}} \|\nabla h\|
\end{equation}
from above in terms of $\inf_{B_R}h $ and, perhaps, a correction term coming from $f$ and some operator data?
In other words - a question for a weak Harnack-type inequality for the gradient.

Any comments, suggestions and references are welcome.
Many thanks!